# angular 2 universal or prerender.io optimization for SEO

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I want to optimization my site for search engines. And I searched two way to do this.

**1 WAY**

To use angular 2 universal for rendering site on server side. I guess this a little difficult and I haven't learnt this yet.

**2 WAY**

Use https://prerender.io/. I guess this very simple.

So my question.
What to use for SEO that it will be more Friendly for search engines and simple? 
Is there any reason to use angular universal or https://prerender.io/ will be enough?

May be sorry for incorrect question but I'm new in this and I want to pick more great way.

Comment: How can you use 2nd with Angular?

Comment: @RomanC Do you want to say 2nd only for angular js?

Comment: @Lestoroer Did you get any solution for prerender.io with angular2?

Comment: @GirishRathod I didn't get.

Comment: Both works, prerender you have to pay for but is easier to set up. Universal is free but more of a hassle.